# Infinite process creation of PHP script by Supervisord

Tags: unix, process, queue, supervisord

This is a Unix/queues/Supervisor question. :)

I'm running PHP command from CLI as one-shot script called in my service. It connects Amazon SQS queue and check if there are jobs to do.

Currently I'm running infinite loop with `supervisord` using `autorestart=true` option. Things work great but `uptime` of this process is always 0:00 (which is understandable) and each time script is called Supervisor creates new process with new PID.

So basically my question is: is this fine to recreate process with new PID all-time-around? It's like: initialize process, run process, end process loop 10x per second. Obviously PID is increasing fast.

Can I leave it as it is or there are other ways to run it as single process and run subprocesses? (Supervisor is running it's jobs already in subprocesses so I guess there cannot be subprocess for subprocess?)

Comment: Did you solve this problem? If so, can you share a solution?

Comment: No, I actually forgot about posting this question. In meantime I moved to `enqueue` library which handles some of my concerns.